# How to sort objects in an array based on a property?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
...

state = {
    text: '',
    time: ''
  }
  render_tasks = () => {
    return (
      <table cellSpacing='0'>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.tasks.map(task => {
              return (
                <tr key={task.id}>
                  <td>{task.text}</td>
                  <td>{task.time}</td>
                  <td 
                    className='remove-btn' 
                    onClick={() => this.props.remove_task(task.id)}>
                      X
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }

...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      tasks: state
  }
}

...
```

What I want to do is to sort the tasks based on the time in ascending order.
I don't know where to write the sort method in the **mapStateToProps** or **render_tasks** function and how to sort the tasks as it's an array of objects, each object has a text, time and id properties.

Comment: I don't use redux so I'm not much use there, but the second part has _tons_ of answers on SO already. Just search for "sort array on object property". That question has been solved, many times over, and should not be in your post.

Comment: You can sort the tasks directly inside `mapStateToProps`